# Undefined Velocity at a certain time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I have a homework problem where the expression for net force on a particle is given by $F(v,t)=-ktv^2$ ($k$ is a positive constant) and $x(0)=0, v(0)=v_{0}$. I was required to solve this differential equation and get an expression for displacement and velocity. So I did the integration $\int mv^{-2}dv=\int -ktdt$ and got $v(t)=\frac{2m}{kt^2+C}$ for some constant $C$. Using the initial condition, I got $C=\frac{m}{v_{0}}$. Then I realized that if the particle's initial velocity is negative, then there is a certain time where velocity is not defined. I can understand this mathematically, but how does it make sense in physics? How is it even possible to have some undefined velocity?

Comment: which differential equation you want to solve ?

Comment: @Eli $F=-ktv^2$, which is $m\frac{dv}{dt}=-ktv^2$

Comment: $~v(t)=-\frac{2\,m}{2\,c\,m-k\,t^2}~$ thus $~v(0)=v_0~,c=?$

Comment: @Eli I mean the constant here does not really matter. My question is that the velocity is undefined at certain points

Comment: $~v(t)=\frac{2\,m\,v_0}{2\,m+k\,t^2\,v_0}~,v_0 > 0$ where is undefined ?

Comment: @Eli, OP says assuming $v_0 < 0, \ \exists t : v(t)$ is undefined.

Comment: @SongofPhysics this doesn't make sense for me ?
so the vehicle goes backwards , if so you have to put signum in the drag equation

Comment: @Eli what vehicle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your velocity $v(t)$ isn't necessarily undefined in general but rather for the given functional form. In other words, there is only a certain domain of validity for your expression. There are often cases in both physics and mathematics where one may have different forms of solutions depending on the domain of validity. If the quantity in general seems undefined for certain extreme cases, one does [asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) to describe the limiting behavior to understand what is going on in the given situation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the context for the force expression you provided (i.e. $F(v, t) = -k t v^2$)? I think that the domain for $v_0$ may be restricted to the non-negative values from the problem’s context.

Comment: This response may be more suited to a comment I believe.

Comment: True but with my current reputation I cannot really comment yet on others’ post, and I believe that the clarification will lead to an answer – if you are able to move this response to the comment section, please do.

Comment: Nope...This question does not specify the value of $v_{0}$. The question just says that the force on the particle is the expression given...That's why I'm so confused